# Trigger animation from viewmodel

Tags: xaml, mvvm

I have a simple design question (I know, no code, it's more about the mvvm pattern): my app shows a map, its viewmodel contains upper left and down-right coordinates.
If I want to move the view, I can change these coordinates.
But what if I want to animate this change ? Like in google earth. I know I can do a storyboard, animate the dependency properties and so on at the view level, but how would I say from the viewmodel "hey, start this storyboard with these target values" ?

The easiest solution would be to fire the event by setting a property bound to the view, but it would require a class that would be known from the view *and* the viewmodel.
Another would be to use a Mediator/Messenger, but I think it's more used to communicate between viewmodels.

I think there must be a cleaner way.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I did not see the point why the ViewModel should tell anything about the animation. Is it bound to any application logic or pure presentation? If pure presentation, then the ViewModel has nothing to do with it. The View can start the animation/storyboard whenever the coordinates have changed.

Comment: @SirRufo actually I'm implementing a command that says "zoom out and pan to see all selected landmarks in the view". This is a command, so it seemed it should be part of the viewmodel. The function itself is part of the customcontrol that is shown (it's pure view) but telling it when, where and how much it has to zoom comes from the viewmodel, as landmarks are parts of it.

Comment: Yes, but that information is in these two coordinates from the VM. That is enough information for the view to zoom in/out and animate it

Answer (score 0):

I found a (rather complicated but consistent) answer from Josh Smith blog.

Here it is, for those who might be interested:
https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2009/04/25/orchestrating-animated-transitions-between-view-and-viewmodel/